# Error: El elemento inicializador no es calculable al momento de la carga en la funcion 'main'

Tags: c, punteros, compilacion

Hola a todos actualmente estoy aprendiendo Lenguaje c y llegue a la parte de los apuntadores, pero resulta que me genera los siguientes errores en el momento de compilación:

```
main.c:22:1: aviso: la definición de datos no tiene tipo o clase de almacenamiento
   22 | p_tasa = &tasa;
      | ^~~~~~
main.c:22:1: aviso: el tipo de dato por defecto es ‘int’ en la declaración de ‘p_tasa’ [-Wimplicit-int]
main.c:22:1: error: tipos en conflicto para ‘p_tasa’
main.c:13:6: nota: la declaración previa de ‘p_tasa’ estaba aquí
   13 | int *p_tasa;
      |      ^~~~~~
main.c:22:10: aviso: la inicialización de ‘int’ desde ‘int *’ crea un entero desde un puntero sin una conversión [-Wint-conversion]
   22 | p_tasa = &tasa;

      |          ^
main.c:22:10: error: el elemento inicializador no es calculable al momento de la carga
main.c: En la función ‘main’:
main.c:28:18: error: argumento de tipo no válido del unario ‘*’ (se tiene ‘int’)
   28 |     printf("%d", *p_tasa);
      |                  ^~~~~~~
make: *** [<integrado>: main] Error 1
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int tasa = 100;

// declaracion de un apuntador y una variable normal.
int *p_tasa;

/**
 * inicializacion de un apuntador, utilizando el operador de direccion (&)
 * cuando es puesto antes del nombre de una variable, regresa la direccion
 * de la misma en la memoria y la almacena en el apuntador.
 */

// almacena la direccion en memoria de tasa en p_tasa.
p_tasa = &tasa;

int main() {


    // imprime el contenido dentro de la variable al a que apunta p_tasa.
    printf("%d", *p_tasa);

    return 0;
}
```

Agradecere mucho su ayuda debido a que soy un novato en C, y realmente no entiendo que
error puedo estar cometiendo.

Comment: No puedes escribir instrucciones como `p_tasa = &tasa;` fuera de una función. Puedes hacer definiciones de variables, pero no instrucciones como esta. Mete esa línea dentro de la función `main` y dejará de darte problemas. Así como lo has escrito, el compilador asume que en esa línea querías poner `int p_tasa = &tasa`, pero resulta que ya tienes definida la variable `p_tasa` antes y con otro tipo: `int * p_tasa;`.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu respuesta, fue de gran ayuda para mi código, ahora me queda claro lo que debo hacer, saludos y de nuevo muchas gracias.

Comment: @SuperG280. Amerita que pongas tu comentario como respuesta. Es un problema que seguro se repetira.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como te he comentado en los comentarios, el problema está en que no puedes escribir instrucciones fuera de una función. y en tu caso:

```
p_tasa = &tasa;
```

tu intención es que fuera una instrucción, pero el compilador asume que fuera de una función solo puede haber definiciones, y por defecto, como te dice en los errores que te salen, entiende que querías decir `int` y se te olvidó.

Este es el error en el que te dice eso:

> aviso: el tipo de dato por defecto es ‘int’ en la declaración de
> ‘p_tasa’

Así que para el compilador tienes dos líneas que entran en conflicto:

```
int *p_tasa;
int p_tasa = &tasa;
```

Misma variable definida dos veces y con tipos distintos...

Solución:

Escribir la instrucción dentro de la función main y quedaría de la siguiente forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int tasa = 100;

// declaracion de un apuntador y una variable normal.
int *p_tasa = NULL;

int main() {

    // almacena la direccion en memoria de tasa en p_tasa.
    p_tasa = &tasa;

    // imprime el contenido dentro de la variable al a que apunta p_tasa.
    printf("%d", *p_tasa);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [tag:c] no tiene nullptr, debería ser NULL

Comment: Cierto, lo corrijo ahora mismo.

Comment: Me queda super claro, agradezco mucho por la respuesta